# Unable to update RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I'm unable to update my RecyclerView. Tried every solution on stackoverflow but nothing helps. I've tried to add layoutmanager in code, hardcode number of items, made new files, checked if I had duplicate files etc.. I also debugged and confirmed that "onAttachedToRecyclerView" is called, but getItemCount and the others i've listed in the adapter are not called except for the constructor

Adapter:

```
    class BaseAdapter(context: Context, val items: List<Item>) : 
    RecyclerView.Adapter<LineBoxAdapter.BaseAdapter>() {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.textView.text = items[position].text
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): 
    ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.simple_item,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val textView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.title)
    }
}
```

Function that updates recyclerView:

```
val listView =
  LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list, viewGroup, 
  false)
  val list = listView.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.
  LinearLayoutManager(context)
  val adapter = BaseAdapter(context, items)
  list.adapter = adapter
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

RECYCLERVIEW:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/items_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:overScrollMode="never"
android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal"
app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />


SIMPLE_ITEM:

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="false"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="25" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you update the code? I think some things have been removed

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `LineBoxAdapter.BaseAdapter` is it an ExpandableList or is it a ViewHolder?

Comment: You probably never actually set the LinearLayoutManager as the layout manager of the RecyclerView.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce LayoutManager set here `app:layoutManager=...`

Comment: @André are you using `setContentView(R.layout.list)` in `onCreate()`?

Comment: Did anything work?

Comment: Hi. I called the function from a rxjava closure, on the background thread. No wonder it didn't work...

Comment: What about my answer, did it work?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using existing class names from API.

I will post my working code.

simple_item:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_simple_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

RecyclerAdapter:

```
class RecyclerAdapter(context: Context, val items: List<Item>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.textView.text = items[position].itemName
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int):
            MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                        R.layout.simple_item,
                        parent,
                        false
                )
        )
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val textView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_simple_item)
    }
}
```

My Activity:

```
class RecyclerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler)

        val recyler = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_activity_recycler)
        val list = mutableListOf(Item("Me"), Item("You"), Item("We"))
        val adapter = RecyclerAdapter(this, list)
        recyler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyler.adapter = adapter

    }
}
```

My Item:

```
class Item(val itemName: String)
```